# Which exception should I throw when switching over type?

Tags: java

I have a type hierarchy where classes `B` and `C` inherit abstract class *`A`*.

I have a code block like this:

```java
if (someVar instanceof B) {
  return "b";
} else if(someVar instanceof C) {
  return "c";
} else {
  throw new Exception("Missing type handling…");
}
```

I would like to know if there is an appropriate exception for this in Java, like `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: If `someVar` is a method argument, then `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IllegalArgumentException` is fine.

[IllegalArgumentException extends RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
> inappropriate argument.

Comment: Additionally, a useful message is a good idea:  `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected argument of type " + (someVar == null ? "null" : someVar.getClass().getName()))`

Comment: @VGR i was indeed thinking about adding this kind of info

Comment: @thchp there is also UnsupportedOperationException which fits the need. However these two exceptions are both runtime exceptions, meaning that you are not forced to try-catch by the compiler. Instead, I would make my own exception extending Exception which will force the caller to implement a fallback for when the type passed along is not the correct one.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ my primary goal is to detect that I forgot to add a new else if statement when I add new types during the development process, so I guess runtime exception is ok

Comment: @thchp then why aren't all the classes (B, C etc.) implementing the same interface which returns a String getSomething() so you won't have to worry about enriching the method any longer?

Comment: This is another question I was about to write on SO: i follow domain driven design, so my domain classes cannot depend on the infrastructure. And I need to create entities depending on whether `someVar` is B or C (those are my domain objects I need to map to entities). But if B and C implement the method, I have to add a dependency to the infrastructure to instantiate the entities.

Answer (score 2):

Sticking to the question you asked, `IllegalArgumentException` is a good exception.

However it doesn't look like you're using class hierarchy correctly. If both `B` and `C` extend `A` which is abstract, then I think that the class A should have an abstract method returning whatever you're checking in your `if` block chain:

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract String getHandling(); //<-- or whatever the correct name is
}
```

So that `B` and `C` can say this:

```
public final class B extends A {
    @Override
    public String getHandling() {
        return "b";
    }
}

public final class C extends A {
    @Override
    public String getHandling() {
        return "c";
    }
}
```

Then, your function that you show partially above would just declare `someVar` being of type `A`:

```
public void yourFunction(A someVar) {
    return someVar.getHandling();
}
```

Like that, you never have to worry about implementing the new `if` each time that someone extend A again.

Either your new class `extends A` (and in that case it is obliged to provide the handling implementation), or simply the compiler won't accept the object in parameter for you.

Comment: This is another question I was about to write on SO: i follow domain driven design, so my domain classes cannot depend on the infrastructure. And I need to create entities depending on whether someVar is B or C (those are my domain objects I need to map to entities). But if B and C implement the method, I have to add a dependency to the infrastructure to instantiate the entities.